# Log in Loop after installing Gnome extensions Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, gnome, graphics, login, amd-graphics

After installing gnome-extensions i got a login loop, so I can't enter on my account.

Therefore i tried to reinstall gnome, gnome-sessions, even gdm3 and lightdm, but doesn't fix's it.

When i tried to go on recovery mode, i was able to enter normally, after getting out of recovery mode i got a message saying that's some graphics drives may not be initiallized, then i continue and i was able to login properly.

So I suspect that for some reason my graphic driver is not being started properly, does any one knows how can i fix that? If not, how do I reinstall my graphic drivers:

Notes:

1. When i try to go in normal way, where login loop is occuring, i can't shutdown and reboot in terminal correctly cause they get in a loop as well, so i have to force shutdown in power button. And startx didn't works too, it acused some amd_gpu error;
2. In tty, i got these data:
   $DISPLAY = None
3. When i tried to manually started gdm3 service it got a loop, so i had to stop the process.
4. My graphic card is an AMD Radeon
5. Here are some data that i got when i was able to login:

- Command: `glxinfo | grep render`

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_render_snorm, 
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

- Command: `sudo lshw -c video`

````
 *-display DISPONÍVEL      
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: UHD Graphics 620
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versão: 07
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuração: latency=0
       recursos: memória:d1000000-d1ffffff memória:b0000000-bfffffff porta de E/S:f000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
  *-display DISPONÍVEL
       descrição: Display controller
       produto: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
       versão: c1
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuração: latency=0
       recursos: memória:c0000000-cfffffff memória:d0000000-d01fffff porta de E/S:e000(tamanho=256) memória:d0200000-d023ffff memória:d0240000-d025ffff```
````

Comment: *What* extensions did you install? How did you install these? Did you use `sudo` at some point?

Comment: I installed all by gnome-extensions window in browser, didn't used any sudo. I discovery that the one who got trouble was 'users themes', that allowed i configure shell theme in gnome-tweak-tool.